# Which parameters prohibit the autoencoder from learning the right distribution?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I have a very minimal example of an autoencoder:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

First I create a data set with the highly correlated variables A and B (that are already normalized)

```
X = pd.DataFrame( (np.random.randn(1000,2)), columns=["A", "B"] )
X["B"] = X["A"] + X["B"]/4
```

Then I setup the autoencoder and train it

```
aeInput = Input(2)
encode = Dense(2, activation='relu')(aeInput)
aeOutput = Dense(2, activation='relu')(encode)

AE = Model(aeInput, aeOutput, name="autoencoder")
AE.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mean_squared_error", )
TrainAE = AE.fit( x=X, y=X, epochs=100, batch_size=2**5,)
```

training looks good and converges smoothly, but when I look at the result the output is mainly zeros.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.kdeplot( X, shade=False, axis=ax)
sns.kdeplot( AE.predict(X), shade=False, axis=ax)
```

[image: Blue is the original distribution, orange the autoencoded one]

This seems very odd to me, because the encoding layer is as large as the input, so a trivial and loss-free solution would simple be to wire the first A neuron straight through, with an activation of 1 and same for the second neuron encoding for B. Why is this not happening? Is there any parameter I use falsely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that your final layer has the `relu` activation, which has a minimum of 0.  If you would like to predict numbers less than 0 on the final layer, you can change the activation to "linear," like this

`aeOutput = Dense(2, activation='linear')(encode)`

Comment: excellent point, but do I understand correctly, that if I only have linear activation functions, I will not be able to fit any non-linearity, right? How does one do that in images? aren't the pixels normalized as well? that's actually a big eye opener, that ReLu can't predict negative values. But sill, why doesn't it get the positive half right then? I mean, that should lower the loss, right?

Comment: Typically, the hidden layers have nonlinear activation functions (relu, tanh, etc.), and the final layer has a linear activation function for a regression problem. The "linear" activation function refers to a linear combination of the weights. The hidden layer(s) allow for non-linear relationships, even though the final layer has a linear activation.

Comment: I think that relu could still get the positive half correct -- I had to try many different random initializations of the weights before I succeeded in getting relu to accurately predict the positive values. I could be wrong, but I think this is due to the "dying relu" problem: [link] (https://medium.com/@danqing/a-practical-guide-to-relu-b83ca804f1f7)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does Keras initialise some weights with negative numbers and does that mean that these are "dead" on initialisation due to the non-existant gradient in the negative realm? that would be so strange...

Comment: Yes. Keras initializes some negative and some positive weights, randomly by default -- you can also specify how the weights are initialized [link] (https://keras.io/initializers/). I think that you're right that some units could be dead at the start (or die very shortly after beginning training).